# python praw get comment and write in file format

Tags: python, web-scraping, praw, reddit

I'm getting a subreddit's contents. The subreddit is `AR`.
I need to get post ID, title, post content, author, post date, score, comments, and comment ID, then write into txt file.
The problems I'm facing now are:

(1) Can I combine comments and comment ID into one file? Thus, it will be `post ID, title, post content, author, post date, score, comments, and comment ID` 
(2) The `selftext` I got has breaklines, so in my output.txt shows like

```
blablabla

blablabla

blablabla
```

For example, [this reddit][1] has multiple breaklines.
I want the content all in one line because the data will be transferred into csv/excel for future analysis.

My code:

```
import praw, datetime, os
reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('AR')
for submission in subreddit.top(limit=1):
    date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)

    for comment in submission.comments:
        print("Comment author: ", comment.author)
        print("Comments: ", comment.body)
        indexFile_comment = open('path' + 'index_comments.txt', 'a+')
        indexFile_comment.write('"' + str(comment.author) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(comment.body) + '"' + '\n')
    print("Post ID: ", submission.id)
    print("Title: ", submission.title)
    print("Post Content: ", submission.selftext)
    print("User Name: ", submission.author)
    print("Post Date: ", date)
    print("Point: ", submission.score)
    indexFile = open('path' + 'index.txt', 'a+')
    indexFile.write('"' + str(submission.id) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(submission.title) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(submission.selftext) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(submission.author) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(date) + '"' + ', ' + '"' + str(submission.score) + '"' + '\n')
    print ("Successfuly writing in file")
    indexFile.close()
```

Comment: To get the self text into one line you could replace `\n` with a space, like this `str.replace("\n", " ")`. I do not understand what you mean by combine the comments and the comment ID however, can you please explain that for me?

Comment: How do I apply str.replace into the selftext code? 
Comments and comment id will just listing following by post ID, title, post content, author, post date, score. So it will look like: post ID, title, selftext, author, date, score, comment ID 1, comment ID 1's comment, comment ID 2, comment ID 2's comment, and so on.

Comment: I fix it by using str(submission.selftext.replace("\n", " "))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the submission in one line you can implement `st.replace("\n"," ")` in your code. Where the variable `st` is `submission.selftext`.

To get the comment ID you could do `comment.id` and to get the body `comment.body` within your for loop.

**Edit:**

In the first line, I have only added `submission.id` and `submission.title` but you can add the rest in the same manner. The loop adds the comments to end of the same string. After the for loop the I replace any new line characters with a space character. You can write `record` to a text file and when you go to the next submission you and append the next `record` to a new line in the text file.

```
record = str(submission.id) + " " + str(submission.title) + " " 
for comment in submission.comments:
    record = record + comment.author + " " + comment.body + " "
record.replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: I know how to get comment id and body, but is it possible to put them all in one line in a txt file? post ID, title, selftext, author, date, score, comment ID 1, comment ID 1's comment, comment ID 2, comment ID 2's comment